# Execute shell command from Ruby and press return

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell

I execute a shell comman inside of ruby on rails with:

```
%x()
```

script that i called from ruby return result and cursor wait for "press return to continue scrolling"

My ruby on rails program wait forever because of this. I write ampersand (&) after command like:

```
%x(my-command &)
```

Now it writes so many times "Press return to continue scrolling" and cursor quit from execution.

How can i complete this command after executing command with or without pressing return?

Comment: It would probably be better to fix the shell command. Did you write it or do you have the source code?

Comment: I have source code, i can change source. But i am looking for if i don't have source code, how can i close execution.

Comment: A program can check whether a TTY is present. In Ruby this would be `$stdin.tty?`. If you can't/don't want to fix the program, you could simulate user input with a [`PTY`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/pty/rdoc/PTY.html).

Comment: Or maybe you could simply pipe a newline to the program: `echo | my-command`